# Jquery error not showing up on firebug

Tags: jquery, github-pages

I am editing this repo on github https://github.com/thiswolf/ttf_html5/tree/gh-pages and i have run into a problem.This is the live page http://thiswolf.github.io/ttf_html5/

The problem is,once i click `add partner` the partner is added  but when i  try clicking `delete partner` nothing happens.What should happen is that,i should get a dialog saying i clicked something.

This is the jquery code

https://github.com/thiswolf/ttf_html5/blob/gh-pages/admin_panel.js

Since the alert does not appear,i have concluded there might be an error somewhere but that error isn't being shown on firebug and i wonder what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(document).on('click', '.delete_partner', function(){` instead. This will bind the event to the document. The way you've declared the function means that it will not bind to dynamically created '.delete_partner' elements; it will only bind to existing '.delete_partner' elements which are at present when the document is ready.

Comment: Shouldn't be binding directly to the document; should be aiming to get as close to the dynamic elements as possible. In this case I'd say `.partners_holder` is the best selector to be calling `.on()` for since that's the element they're being appended to when created.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't look at the HTML, but I agree with your point.

Comment: Here is how i fixed it https://github.com/thiswolf/ttf_html5/commit/c05f8c1d30b9bb0ab2697e71b12ac23a195d91fe